# Laplacian of a Function depending on r in Polar Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

From a bank of exams:

> Let $u(x,y) = f(r)$ be a smooth
>   function in the plane that depends
>   only on $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.
>   Compute $\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy}$
>   in terms of $f$ and its derivatives.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Two_dimensions) states that the Laplace operator in polar coordinates is $$\Delta f = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \left( r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2},$$ which I suppose I could memorize directly, but I thought there might be an easier way.

I tried to prove this directly, by thinking that $$ u_{xx} = \frac{d^2f}{dr^2} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} + \frac{df}{dr} \frac{\partial ^2r}{\partial x^2}$$ and 
$$ u_{yy} = \frac{d^2f}{dr^2} \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} + \frac{df}{dr} \frac{\partial ^2r}{\partial y^2}.$$ 
But then I get stuck at $$ u_{xx} + u_{yy} = \frac{d^2f}{dr^2} \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + \frac{df}{dr}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
=  \frac{d^2f}{dr^2} \frac{r(\cos \theta + \sin \theta)}{r} + \frac{df}{dr}\frac{1}{r}.$$ Any idea on where I'm going wrong? It looks like I need $\displaystyle{\frac{r(\cos \theta + \sin \theta)}{r} = 1}$.

Comment: Sorry I can't follopwup for a while, but you can see this as an issue of finding the representation of/for a function in a given coordinate system, i.e., functions have expressions depending on the manifold charts where the function takes its values. See, e.g., John Lee's 1st Chapter on Smooth Manifolds book.HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we have
$$
u_x=f_rr_x, u_{xx}=f_rr_{xx}+r_x(f_{rr}r_x)\text{ similarly for } y,
$$
$$
u_{xx}+u_{yy}=f_rr_{xx}+r_x(f_{rr}r_x)+f_rr_{yy}+r_y(f_{rr}r_y)
=f_{rr}(r_x^2+r_y^2)+f_r(r_{xx}+r_{yy}).
$$
with
$$
r_x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, r_{xx}=\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \text{ similarly for } y
$$
we have
$$
u_{xx}+u_{yy}=f_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}f_r.
$$
of course if $f$ depends on $\theta$ it gets more complicated

Comment: And here I see exactly where my calculations went wrong. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the "inner derivative" in one factor of the product when taking the second derivative. It should be $$u_{xx} = \frac{d^2f}{dr^2} \left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \frac{df}{dr} \frac{\partial ^2r}{\partial x^2}.$$

Comment: Aha! so I forgot to use the chain rule and introduce a second $\partial r/\partial x$ when I was differentiating $df/dx$. Thank you, much appreciated. I wish I could mark both answers as correct...