# PDE Cartesian/Polar forms and Numerical Solver issues

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, polar-coordinates, laplacian

Starting with, $ur^2 = u_0r_0^2$, where $u$ is my dependent variable, $u_0$ is the initial/constant value of $u$ at $r_0$, I can take two derivatives with respect to the radial distance, r, and obtain the ODE,

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{4}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{2}{r^2}u=0\tag{1}\label{1}$$

I want to write this in terms of Cartesian coordinates to be solved using the [MATLAB PDE Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/pde/features.html#supported-pdes), and thus far I've considered three ways to do it (my questions are at the end).

OPTION 1: Hand-wavy

Given 
$$x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$$
it can be shown via the chain rule that,
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\cos\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\sin\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
and the 2D Laplacian in Cartesian coordinates is,
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}$$

And from the starting equation I know $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}=0$, thus, I get,
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{3}{r}\left(\cos\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+sin\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{2}{r^2}u=0\tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{3}{x^2+y^2}\left(x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{2}{x^2+y^2}u=0\tag{2i}\label{2i}$$
*(Note: the equations labelled with an "i" represent the forms I will code/implement in MATLAB's PDE solver)*

OPTION 2: Direct-Cartesian

Say I start with $u(x^2+y^2)=C$ and simply take the Laplacian using Cartesian coordinates. I get,
$$\left(x^2+y^2\right)\nabla^2u+2\nabla\left(x^2+y^2\right)\cdot\nabla u+u\nabla^2\left(x^2+y^2\right)=0$$
which, provided my algebra is correct, becomes,

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{4}{x^2+y^2}\left(x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{4}{x^2+y^2}u=0\tag{3i}\label{3i}$$

*Please note the difference in coefficients between \eqref{2i} and \eqref{3i}.*

OPTION 3: Canonical?

Following [another example](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/21C.w11/polar-lap.pdf), an honest conversion of \eqref{1} from polar to cartesian, with no short-cuts, should result in,

$$\cos^2\theta\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+ 2\cos\theta\sin\theta\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} + \sin^2\theta\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{4}{r}\left(\cos\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\sin\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{2}{r^2}u=0\tag{4}\label{4}$$

$$\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+ 2\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{4}{x^2+y^2}\left(x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{2}{x^2+y^2}u=0\tag{4i}\label{4i}$$

*Once again, different coefficients.* Here are where my questions come in... 
**QUESTIONS** 
(1) (a) Does everyone generally agree that \eqref{3i} is more rigorous/accurate than \eqref{2i}? If not, why not? (b) What are your thoughts on the correctness of \eqref{4i} vs \eqref{3i}? (c) As a side note, in terms of accuracy, MATLAB seems to work better with \eqref{2i} using linear triangular elements, but I'm not sure why. Any insight on that would also be appreciated.
(2) I would like to implement \eqref{4} but MATLAB does not implement cross derivatives directly. Instead, they must take the form,
$$\nabla\cdot\left(c\nabla u\right)$$
If $c$ is a constant, we get back the Laplacian with a constant coefficient. Although that's easy to implement, it does not strictly apply to \eqref{4}. Here's why: If $c$ is a non-constant scalar, we know,
$$\nabla\cdot\left(c\nabla u\right)=\nabla c\cdot\nabla u + c\nabla^2u$$
If $c$ is a matrix, I can do [something like](https://sundoc.bibliothek.uni-halle.de/habil-online/06/06H055/t7.pdf),
$$\nabla\cdot\left(c\nabla u\right)=\left(\nabla\cdot c\right)\cdot \nabla u + c\cdot\cdot\left(\nabla\nabla u\right)$$
plus rearranging terms to produce an equation equivalent to \eqref{4} that the solver can handle ($\nabla\nabla u$ is the Hessian). HOWEVER, \eqref{4} was obtained using the fact that $\partial()/\partial r = \cos\theta\partial()/\partial x+\sin\theta\partial()/\partial y$. That is, $\theta$ is held constant. Thus, I cannot express $c$ in terms of sines and cosines because (a) treating them as the constants that they are prohibits me from implementing them in MATLAB's format, (b) if I attempt to force MATLAB to use sines and cosines, the MATLAB solver will attempt to differentiate them anyway, which is equivalent to replacing $\cos\theta$ with $x/r$. The problem I see with using $\cos\theta=x/r$ is that I am essentially creating a circular argument, which undermines the logic behind \eqref{4}. In other words, \eqref{4i} is okay **as-is** but if I try to rearrange terms, causing $\nabla$ to operate on the second order term coefficients, such as $x^2/r^2$, that will introduce a fallacy into my equation and the results will be garbage. Question -> Does everyone agree that it would be **wrong** to implement,

$$\nabla\cdot\left(\begin{bmatrix}x^2/r^2 & xy/r^2\\xy/r^2 & y^2/r^2\\\end{bmatrix}\nabla u\right)=\left(\nabla\cdot \begin{bmatrix}x^2/r^2 & xy/r^2\\xy/r^2 & y^2/r^2\\\end{bmatrix}\right)\cdot \nabla u + \begin{bmatrix}x^2/r^2 & xy/r^2\\xy/r^2 & y^2/r^2\\\end{bmatrix}\cdot\cdot\left(\nabla\nabla u\right)$$
in an attempt to create something equivalent to \eqref{4}?
Here are some related stack questions I looked into:
[Laplacian from cartesian to polar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997250/laplacian-from-cartesian-to-polar)
[Laplacian of a Function depending on r in Polar Coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30844/laplacian-of-a-function-depending-on-r-in-polar-coordinates?rq=1)
[How to transform a Laplacian operator from (x,y) coordinate system to polar system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36121/how-to-transform-a-laplacian-operator-from-x-y-coordinate-system-to-polar-syst)
[Transforming the Laplace operator from Polar to Cartesian coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/transforming-the-laplace-operator-from-polar-to-cartesian-coordinates)
See also:
http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jdg/AECHAIN.PDF
http://planetmath.org/derivationofthelaplacianfromrectangulartosphericalcoordinates

Answer (score 1):

For question 2: I manually confirmed that I *can* derive an equivalent expression by using directional derivatives, rather than polar coordinates (some might consider this distinction to be semantics). Doing it this way, there is no need to "replace" $\cos\theta$ with $x/r$, and I can perform the rearrangements that I wanted to perform.

For question 1: Form 1 is definitely hand-wavy, but usable. Form 3 is the correct expression. Form 2 differs from the others because of the fact that $\nabla$ is not a directional derivative. As such, it might work but probably requires modified boundary conditions relative to the other two forms.